# Why is $injector is not defined

Tags: angularjs

Getting the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $injector is not defined
```

The error comes up in the console.

Here is how I'm coding it into my controller:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

    angular.module('DIApp', [])
    .controller('DIController', DIController);

    function DIController ($scope, $filter, $injector) {
        $scope.name = "Yaakov";

        $scope.upper = function() {
            var upCase = $filter('uppercase');
            $scope.name = upCase($scope.name);
        };
    }

    console.log($injector.annotate(DIController));

    function AnnotateMe(name, job, blah) {
        return "Blah!";
    }


})();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <body>
      <h1>Dependency Injection in Javascript
                (and Angularjs</h1>
      <div ng-controller="DIController">
          <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-blur="upper()">
      </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Declare $injector as above

```
var $injector = angular.injector();
```

and then

```
console.log($injector.annotate(DIController));
```